# APNS JSON PAYLOAD - more arguments

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

I need to add some arguments to a json payload for APNS service. How can i do this?
this is the documentation of apple: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1

When i try to send a message with close and view buttons, i need to add two more arguments that my mobile application needs. 
Any idea?

Comment: No, until you show us your code.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not sure if you got the answer yet. But this is what the documentation mentions

> Providers can specify custom payload
>   values outside the Apple-reserved aps
>   namespace. Custom values must use the
>   JSON structured and primitive types:
>   dictionary (object), array, string,
>   number, and Boolean.

So in order to add custom values to your payload, just add them as key-value pairs in your payload. Something like this

```
{
    "aps":{
        "alert":"Your Message",
        "sound":"push1.wav"
     },
     "custom_key1":"value1",
     "custom_key2":"value2"
}
```

Here `custom_key1` and `custom_key2` are your custom keys and `value1` and `value2` are their values.

Comment: Im still having the same problem with APNS. 
When i receive the notification, im only have a "close" button, but i need the "close" and "view" button. 
When i send this Payload:  
{
 "aps":{"alert":"test Message"},
 "acme2" : ["bang","whiz"]
} 
i have the buttons that i need, but, how can i put two more arguments like: "argument1":"value1","argument2":"value2" ?.

Comment: the example I have above uses 2 arguments (custom key1 and key2). To get the keys you have to handle the app delegate method.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is still wondering :

```
$body = (array('aps' => array('alert' => $message,'sound' => $sound_file_wav),   "some_key" => "custom_id"));
$payload = json_encode($body);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following in PHP

```
$title = 'My Test Message';
$sound = 'doorbell.caf';
$msgpayload=json_encode(array('aps' => array('alert' => $title,'sound' => $sound,)));


$response = $sns->publish(array(
    'TopicArn' => $TopicArn,
    'MessageStructure' => 'json',
    'Message' => json_encode(array(
        'default' => $title,
        'APNS_SANDBOX' => $msgpayload
    ))
));
```