# How add image in Apple Local/Push notification message?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

In some iOS games i see images in local/push notifications: hearts, smiles, ...
How i can get this feature?
At this time i already using a en.lproj and Localizable.strings. May be the solution there?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess it is not really a "image" in the meaning of a pixel graphic 
but a character from the Emojii keyboard you can add to any text on your iPhone.

And then it is the same question as here [Sending Emoji in Push Notifications via PHP on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012485/sending-emoji-in-push-notifications-via-php-on-ios) .