# Can I send an image with Apple's Push Notification Service?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I need to show an image whenever my application receive Notification.

Does Apple push notification support **image** sending?

**Update**

If above thing is not possible can we show image from url on `UIAlertview` when we receive notification.

Comment: You can send URL of your image within notification

Comment: So can we show image from URL on alertview?

Comment: Brief about your plan of showing an image on alertview - I'll be more than interested to know its possibility.

Comment: Of course we can show image on alert, you can find that on below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323557/image-in-uialertview

Comment: Yep. Thanks - But to answer your question, No - Push notification cannot send images with its allowable payload limit.

Comment: Yes but when we can show alertview in didReceiveRemoteNotification method we can show image from url, and url can we sent from server

Comment: Yes. Definitely possible:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update!** iOS 10 introduced the ability to add media attachments to push notifications. So now we have the ability to include an image in a push notification. [Source: Andrew from comments, and other tutorials that show how to do this, such as [this one](https://medium.com/@tsif/ios-10-rich-push-notifications-with-media-attachments-a54dc86586c2).]

---

No. The notification payload can be up to 256 bytes long. You can send an image only if the encoded image size plus the rest of the payload is no more bigger than that... useless.

You can, however, use **launch-image** property from **alert** apn dictionary to specify an image from app bundle that will be used at app launch.

Or you can send a URL from which the image can be downloaded within the app.

Please take a look at [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1)

Comment: So can we show image from URL on alertview?

Comment: Nop, the notification icon will be always the app icon. You can't do anything with the notification, it's only sent to device, device takes care of showing the alert. You can only use the notification when the user opens the app, read the data and act according.

Comment: **Update!** iOS 10 introduced the ability to add media attachments to push notifications. So now we have the ability to include an image in a push notification.

Answer (score 2):

As far as Push Notifications go, when the user actions the notification or the notification is received while the app is in the foreground, the app will only get the push message payload. The only intent is to let the user know that there is new content.

Hence, you should not be using Push Notifications to deliver content to your app. Your app should be responsible for pulling any new content from your backend server as soon as it is in a position to do so.

**UPDATE:** However, if you mean "emoji" [this might help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012485/sending-emoji-in-push-notifications-via-php-on-ios)

Comment: From iOS 9 payload size becomes 2KB.