# iPhone push notifications information

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to transfer any information in the push notification beside `"badge"` `"sound"` and `"text"`?

For example, in the app `"whatsapp"` when a push notification appears and pressed, the app is opened but not going to the conversation. My guess is that it can't know what conversation to go to. But then I saw that in facebook messenger app it actually goes in the conversation. how does the messenger app know that what conversation to go to?

Also, if it is possible to transfer information, why is it that apps like `whatsapp` don't use it and also ask you for your name so it will be displayed in the push?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, indeed. But your message size (in bytes) must not pass a certain threshold Apple has imposed. You can then pull that info in the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` using something like this:

```
NSDictionary* dictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
```

Where dictionary contains your push notification info.

Comment: so, why is it in your opinion that whatsapp and all other apps dont do that?

Comment: Yes, definitely. That's the last method called before your view controller is pushed into the navigation stack. Based on the info you get in that dictionary you can present a custom viewcontroller.

Answer (score 3):

There are apps that have permission to run in the background and other apps that have not. May be facebook messenger app have this permission and can receive push notifications and do whatever is needed to go to the correct conversation or user. I don't know if this is true but it could be a possible reason.

Answer (score 2):

in this method we can display pushnotifications alerts and their action according to our app

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo   
{


    NSLog(@"did receive remore notification %@",userInfo);
    if(isForground)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: so, why is it in your opinion that whatsapp and all other apps dont do that?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at this documentation section [Examples of JSON Payloads](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW15)

At the bottom you can see custom payload examples like:

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You got your emails.",
        "badge" : 9,
        "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
    },
    "acme1" : "bar",
    "acme2" : 42
}
```

Where `acme1` and `acme2` are custom data that you can pass to the push notification and get it inside you app after launched.

The data is available through UIApplicationDelegate callbacks as described here [Handling Local and Remote Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4)

Comment: so, why is it in your opinion that whatsapp and all other apps dont do that?

Comment: I dont quite understand the question. How do you know that whatsapp does not do it like this?

Comment: when you get a message and press on the notification the app just launch itself to the last place that it was. in android it takes you to the specific conversation.  i know it because i tried and saw.

Comment: You can shurely achieved this with the callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add more arguments in your payload. In our app we add something like
groupID, or type.
See this stack overflow for adding more payload arguments

[APNS JSON PAYLOAD - more arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954882/apns-json-payload-more-arguments)

Comment: so, why is it in your opinion that whatsapp and all other apps dont do that?

Comment: maybe it is a feature to be implemented in the future. You know, companies have strict deadline and they cut off some feature. Another thing is that, they never got that idea, it's a very good idea but never thought of it, usually the developers know of that capability of features but the designers are not aware it exist, since only a few app does that

Comment: you know that in android it works in all of the apps... so the designers must know about it.  I guess there is no clear answer for that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the message size doesnt exceed **256** bytes.It is the threshold limit for the payload

Comment: so, why is it in your opinion that whatsapp and all other apps dont do that?