# Calling a function with push notification

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have made my own push notification server for my iPhone app. I am sending different push notifications to client devices. Now with one special of the notification, I want to call a specific function in appDelegate or anywhere.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Whilst I like the idea +1. Are you allowed to do this or will apple reject it. I thought you could only notify the user they had a some sort of notification not start running different functions without them knowing.

Comment: @Popeye its just a popup first that will notify them if they want to perform a specific func or not :) I see no reason for objection

Comment: OK. I thought you wanted to do it without letting them know. Misunderstanding that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot specify a function to call DIRECTLY

when the app is launched, `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` is called and passed the note in the options under `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey`

when the app is running, you have `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`

---

you could pass the NAME of a method to call with the notification! so:

```
...
NSString *methodName = [notificationUserInfo objectForKey:@"methodName"];
[self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(methodName)];
...
```

the server side JSON would contain the methodName key:
as seen here we can Include all we like [APNS JSON PAYLOAD - more arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954882/apns-json-payload-more-arguments)

```
{"aps":{"alert":"APP_NAME': BLA_BLA_BLA","sound":"default"}, "methodName":"xy"}
```

Comment: so on the Server add methodName="xyz" to the userInfo JSON

Comment: {"aps":{"alert":"APP_NAME': BLA_BLA_BLA","sound":"default"}} is my payload currently, what u are suggesting?

Comment: @MuhammadUmar see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954882/apns-json-payload-more-arguments so in your case 
  
{"aps":{"alert":"APP_NAME': BLA_BLA_BLA","sound":"default"}, "methodName":"xy"}

Answer (score 1):

When user launch app via notification, it may have different scenarios:

it wasn't launched, then app launching in default way and you can handle notification in such way:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UILocalNotification *remoteNotif =
        [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (remoteNotif) {
        //handle remote notification
    }
    ....
}
```

if app was in background or foreground, called delegate method

```
- application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: {
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive){
        //application was in foreground
    } else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive){
        //application was in background
    }
}
```

Also, if application was in foreground - system does not show alerts, don't change badge icon or playback sound - you should handle notification completely by yourself

Comment: The question is how will I get to know what type of notification is being sent. to call a function or not :)

Comment: @MuhammadUmar see my answer. but he is implicity right. you cannot do so DIRECTLY :) but there is a way that I have used in the past too