# IOS Push Notification - play two audio files

Tags: ios, audio, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

can I play two audio files one by one?

```
{aps ={alert = "Hello";sound = "sound1.caf, sound2.caf";};}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can not, iOS will only play one sound file from the apps main bundle.

Your option is to add more sounds files with the combined sound of the other files to your apps bundle. Also be aware that the maximum of play time does not exceed 30 seconds or it will not be played.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you asked for (you can play one audio no problem, but two, I don't know) but you could try a little workaround.

When the app launches after the notification was received, you can execute a selector that plays your audio files one after another.

You could look here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14588454/1349663

Comment: With this solution the sound files will only be played if the user open the app from the push notification. Not when you receive the notification.

Comment: Yup. Like I said, not exactly what he asked for, just sharing an idea.

Comment: Indeed I just wanted to add that to your answer.